# View today's birthdays a second time on m.facebook.com

Tags: facebook

On Facebook Mobile https://m.facebook.com the birthdays' link disappears once you have clicked it, and only reappears the next day with new birthdays.

What if I want to view it a second time?

The Events page only shows 3 of today's birthdays randomly.
The birthdays page only shows birthdays starting from tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the direct URL for access at any time:

https://m.facebook.com/browse/birthdays/?_rdr